# Export each column of a pandas dataframe as txt

Tags: python, pandas

How can I export each column of a pandas dataframe as a new txt file with the name of the txt.file being the colum name and each cell entry being seperated by a new line "\n"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html) in loop:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c].to_csv(c + '.txt', index=False)
```

Comment: I think the OP was asking about exporting to txt, hence maybe "np.savetxt" could be applied instead of "to_csv" , right ?

Comment: Glad can help you!